# Eliminating multiple Tr tags to get correct count

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the count of rows in a table but due to the tr tag opening and closing, it's being counted twice and hence the count is not proper. That is what i have debugged.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class back 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/bangladesh-v-south-africa-2015/engine/match/817213.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='st_1']")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]"));
List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println("No of rows are " +rows.size());
    }
}
```

Please suggest what should be the correct way to get number of rows or there is some problem in my xpath.

Comment: Also when i used the following code for calculating no of columns it's giving wrong columns too, kindly suggest: for (WebElement currentrow: rows)
 {
  int i=0;
  List<WebElement> eachcolumn=driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  i++;
  System.out.println("No of columns are"+eachcolumn.size());
 }

Comment: It should not consider the closing tags. Is your table plain html table or some javascript based table?

Comment: You can check using the url provided in code

Comment: Go to it and click on scorecard

Comment: The code should display the correct number of rows. It's how the scorecard is designed. Can u update the question with what do u expect as the row and what row no. are u getting?

Comment: I am getting 25 rows in the output and if i calculate there are 12 or 13 rows for there which i can calculate

Comment: That is expected. I can see 25 rows: 1 for heading, 11 for players, 11 that displays player dismal when u click plus icon, 1 each for heading, extra-wrap and total-wrap. So, maybe u can still update the question for what rows u actually need?

Comment: Yes i need only for the 11 players. How can i go about that? @Manu You got it right. I basically want to calculate only those rows and nothing else and corresponding columns to each of the players. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find only the 11 players in the scorecard, you can use below XPath:

```
//tr[not(@class='dismissal-detail' or @class='tr-heading' or @class='extra-wrap' or @class='total-wrap')]
```

**Edit:**

Below is the code to find the elements:

```
List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.xpath("/tbody/tr[not(@class='dismissal-detail' or @class='tr-heading' or @class='extra-wrap' or @class='total-wrap')]");
```

or

```
List<WebElement> rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]//tr[not(@class='dismissal-detail' or @class='tr-heading' or @class='extra-wrap' or @class='total-wrap')]"));
```

Comment: List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[not(@class='tr-heading' or class='dismissal-detail')]"));

Comment: u r welcome! its just that previously it was searching for these tags in all tables and hence gave 50 rows. btw bangladesh seems to win this test ;)

Comment: Yep i also mistakenly put as driver. Whereas it should have been table.. hence the issue. Also you would have to use Single quotes for value of class atrribute and not double. You can edit that

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var rowsCounter =  driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("table\tbody\tr")).count;
```

So you need to check how much tr elements is exist in the table. If there is several tables, you need to select correct table in xpath.

another way is the same, but count how much elements of \tr\td[1] exist